# Bootstrap float left and float right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm very new to bootstrap so this is probably an easy question for most. I have a navbar, want two nav items and an input field to be on the left side of the navbar. With the two remaining nav items on the right. I have tried messing with the classes to make this happen and using the "float-left" and "float-right" classes but no joy :(

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">L'amour</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item float-left">
              <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item float-left">
              <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Testimonial</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <input class='form-control' type='text' name='search' placeholder='Search for wedding...'>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item float-right">
              <a class="nav-link float-right" href="order.php">Order Wesbite</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown float-right">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             Account
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="signIn.php">Login</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="sign-up">Sign up</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="homeUser.php">Account details</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">L'amour</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    
      <!-- left menu -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="order.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="order.php">Testimonial</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <input class='form-control' type='text' name='search' placeholder='Search for wedding...'>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <!-- right menu -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="order.php">Order Wesbite</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Account
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signIn.php">Login</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="sign-up">Sign up</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="homeUser.php">Account details</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate menu into two ul left and right use class mr-auto for left and  my-0 for the right one

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">L'amour</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item float-left">
              <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item float-left">
              <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Testimonial</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <input class='form-control' type='text' name='search' placeholder='Search for wedding...'>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav my-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link float-right" href="order.php">Order Wesbite</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown float-right">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             Account
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="signIn.php">Login</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="sign-up">Sign up</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="homeUser.php">Account details</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/v00oy85h/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should wrap your `nav` items in different `ul`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">L'amour</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item float-left">
          <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item float-left">
          <a class="nav-link float-left" href="order.php">Testimonial</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for wedding...">
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="order.php">Order Wesbite</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Account
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signIn.php">Login</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="sign-up">Sign up</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="homeUser.php">Account details</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> Note: View the snippet in full screen

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to use clearfix class to parent class that contain float-left or float-right class